# My admin menu bar is empty

Tags: admin, magento2.2, adminhtml, migration, php-7.1

After a migration my menu bar is empty. I tried to clear cache, create a new admin user and also deploy static files and nothing works.
Any help is highly appreciated.

The HTML looks like this

```
<body data-container="body" data-mage-init='{"loaderAjax": {}, "loader": { "icon": "https://example.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/loader-2.gif"}}' id="html-body" class="adminhtml-dashboard-index page-layout-admin-1column">
        <div class="menu-wrapper">                        <a
            href="https://example.com/admin_99987/admin/"
            data-edition="Community Edition"            class="logo">
            <img class="logo-img" src="https://example.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/magento-icon.svg"
            alt="Magento Admin Panel"/>
        </a>
    </div>
```

The error I get initially is :

```
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(401): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Crypt->__construct('f2acade8e064651...', 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL...', 'MCRYPT_MODE_CBC', 'MgcwQ29XY5KVa14...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(313): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->getCrypt('f2acade8e064651...', 2, 'MgcwQ29XY5KVa14...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Backend/Encrypted.php(113): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->decrypt('urwAMNJtVY5DNFh...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/MetadataConfigTypeProcessor.php(123): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted->processValue('0:2:MgcwQ29XY5K...')
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/MetadataConfigTypeProcessor.php(141): Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataConfigTypeProcessor in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Crypt.php on line 59
[07-Jul-2021 10:26:59 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 81
[07-Jul-2021 10:26:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 394
[07-Jul-2021 10:26:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_MODE_CBC - assumed 'MCRYPT_MODE_CBC' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 395
[07-Jul-2021 10:26:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\Encryption\mcrypt_module_open() in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Crypt.php:59
```

but this disappears may be due to caching?

[image: Admin menu bar]

Comment: Is this production or dev environment? Start looking at logs var/log/debug.log and var/log/exception.log. Also enable error code printing https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/display-error-enable-error-reporting-magento-2.html Try looking at some tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNtTeFqkcWQ

Comment: I tried both production and dev mode in Magento. I looked at the logs and also PHP logs. Nothing I could find. Also no problem in the front end as well. All the js were loaded and executed well.

Comment: Enable error printing and you should be able to see at least some errors. Which version are you migrating to?

Comment: Yeah with error printing I got an error with encryption but then I downgraded PHP to 7.1 and then it stopped. Not migrating versions but migrating to a new server.

Comment: You need to give more information if you want help(thats why somebody downvoted your question). Whats the error on the Admin page?

Comment: Yeah, I am new to this but I have literally no errors at all. Everything runs without error on the main site and the admin page produces no PHP, Magento or Nginx error. Also, no error in the frontend too! I am new to Magento so was thinking it may be a normal scenarios but did not find anything. I suspected admin roles and also checked the db and the admin had access to :all . Now I am just out of ideas.

Comment: No, there should be error. Try right click on admin page and "View Source'. Sometimes white page hides the error.

Comment: Yes I did that also clicked in inspect to see if there are some network problem. The menu part looks like this.

Comment: Please update your original posts with screenshots / debug.log / exception.log entries. Make sure to remove your store folder name (in the name of security).

Comment: Yes, i was getting the error when I clear the cache but after that, I never get this error. So it could be linked with this?

Comment: check if you have installed mcrypt. Maybe create phpinfo.php and put phpinfo() to see if mcrypt is installed. Here is the list of Magento 2.2 requirements: https://blog.landofcoder.com/magento-2-2-requirements/
At some point you should really migrate away from 2.2 - its very old and is not supported anymore. It has a ton of security vulnerabilities.